# Port to connect to rostest rosmaster after Indigo

Tags: ros, ros-comm, rostest, ros-master-uri, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Connecting to rosmater with specific port number](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest/Connecting%20to%20the%20rostest%20master) used to be possible. I see [this pull request](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/468) against `Indigo` that randomizes the `rosmaster` port for `rostest`.
Does this mean that there is now no way to connect to rosmater during rostest?

(I'm seeing [an issue](https://github.com/ros-drivers/leap_motion/pull/17) that only occurs to me during rostest. I want to see values set in Parameter Server for debug purpose.)

```
$ dpkg -p ros-indigo-ros-comm | grep Ver
Version: 1.11.13-0trusty-20150429-190011-0700
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208361/port-to-connect-to-rostest-rosmaster-after-indigo/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-05-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/637 replaced the earlier pr and was merged and now `rostest --reuse-master pkg foo.test` will use the standard ROS_MASTER_URI port.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-19**:
But is there a way to catkin_make run_tests and reuse-master?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in the referenced PR `rostest` has been modified for Indigo to use a random port by default (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/467). That allows to run multiple rostests in parallel which significantly speeds up testing.

For your use case it would be good if you could override the port using a command line argument to `rostest`. Since the internal API of rostest still allows to configure a custom port it should be straight forward to add a command line argument for that. It would be great if you could create a PR for this feature.

After that the referenced wiki page should be updated as well.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-05-04**:
Thanks, and [PR is opened](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/614).

**Comment by [Peaches491](https://answers.ros.org/users/7456/peaches491/) on 2015-06-18**:
Any update on this PR? It's still not merged as of 6/18/2015

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-18**:
The PR fails some unit tests which need to be fixed by the PR author before it can be merged.